# Can normal users monitor URLs accessing by root?

Tags: networking

I'm in linux normal account, and not in the router, and want to know what URLs the root user is accessing (not only apt), can and how to do it without `sudo`?

For example, `sudo apt update` will get the packages lists from ubuntu.com, which is called URL

Comment: What do you mean by "URL access"? I sure hope `root` is not browsing the web on your machine.

Comment: Why should a user have rights to snoop on another user?

Comment: @roaima: To check where the system have connected to

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

That would be a huge security problem, is a normal user could monitor the network trafic of another user, especially root.

If you find a way to do this, you should probably report it as a security issue.

Comment: I used `sudo apt update` to connect to the ubuntu server, does the running program with normal user can read the output from the terminal even it is minimized? Perhaps other questions, reading the screenshot.